# awk, dividing lines in a file into two output strings

Tags: awk, string-concatenation

I'm trying to create two files from an input file. The output files will share the same header information (taken from the original file) and I then want to allocate the subsequent lines based on a value.

At the moment I'm stuck as it seems that when a line fails the "if" statement, the last value it had is still added I think.

My input looks something like this:-

```
#START  STOP  INFO
1  100  700  Q=2;S=40;LENGTH=600
2  300  350  Q=5;S=50;LENGTH=50
3  567  601  Q=3;S=2;LENGTH=34
```

My code looks like this:-

```
awk -v short="" -v long=""  'BEGIN{FS="\t"}{if ($1 !~/#/) {sub(/.*LENGTH=/, ""); sub(/;.*/, ""); if ($NF >= 500 ) { long=$0 }}  else { long=$0; short=$0 }}{print long}' test.txt
```

My output for the long file looks like this:-

```
#START STOP INFO
1  100   700  Q=2;S=40;LENGTH=600
1  100   700  Q=2;S=40;LENGTH=600
1  100   700  Q=2;S=40;LENGTH=600
```

And output for the short file looks like this:-

```
#START STOP INFO
#START STOP INFO
#START STOP INFO
```

Whereas I want "long" should look like:-

```
#START STOP INFO
1  100   700  Q=2;S=40;LENGTH=600
```

And "short" to be:-

```
#START STOP INFO
2  300  350  Q=5;S=50;LENGTH=50
3  567  601  Q=3;S=2;LENGTH=34
```

(i.e. the length value for the next two lines are less than 500 and so should be added to the "short" string, but for some reason the previous line- the one that is greater than 500- is being added twice)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting. Could you tell us what the input looks like?

Comment: Thanks, actually been posting for a while- it's always proved useful before!
My input essentially looks like ( although I can't get the newlines to show.. each should be on a new line):-


`#LENGTH
600
100
200
`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well this seems to work, not sure if anyone's got any improvement suggestions?

```
awk -v short="" -v long=""  '{if ($1 ~/#/){long = long "\n" $0; short = short "\n" $0} else { line=$0; sub(/.*LENGTH=/, ""); sub(/;.*/, ""); if ( $NF >= 500 ){long = long "\n" line } else { short = short "\n" line}}}END{print long, short}' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you intend to do is the following :

```
awk -v long="longfile.txt" -v short="shortfile.txt" \
    -v val=500 -F "="                               \
    '/^#/{ print > long; print > short } # print header
    ($NF>val) { print > long; next }     # print long file
    { print > short }' <file>            # print short file
```